# Find and Replace SQL Query with Regex

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I have some links in database like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/full/?api=0aca610f4a9983fc1fa30brs6c302f970ae87c29da&amp;url=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3c0Mi56aXBwfseXNoYXJlLmNvbS92L1IwVlNwZkk4L2ZpbGUuaHRtbA==&amp;type=2" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">www.example.net/v/R0V82dSpfI8/file.html</a>

<a href="https://example.com/full/?api=sd4a5sdf540c1fa30b6c302f9704a6sadf&amp;url=asdfa54asd5fa5sdfa8dRcFFcafasdf==&amp;type=2" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">example.org/000hcwoc0kcwy1/545da45a.rar.html</a>
```

I need a "find and replace" SQL query that will 
find the anchor text, add https:// and put it in the href tag.

Final HTML should be like this, based on the second example:

```
<a href="https://example.org/000hcwoc0kcwy1/545da45a.rar.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">example.org/000hcwoc0kcwy1/545da45a.rar.html</a>
```

I am not exactly a developer and I really hate regex because I don't understand it. Could you help me to fix this problem please?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?   `regexp_replace()` is only available starting MySQL 8+.  What is the "anchor text"?  What is the "href tag"

Comment: Online regex debugging tools like 
[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3giB5Yzt4sJEBcVf) assist in visually debugging regular expressions.

Comment: @TARIK SUCU , Are these values available in a single column of the table?

Comment: Gordon : Server version: 10.3.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server
its support
Danblack : i will try
Arun : Yes, it is wordpress table and that html's are in content column of post table

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regex functions, although it is a bit complicated because MySQL/MariaDB do not support capturing group.

You can identify the part of the string that needs to be replaced with regex `'href="[^"]+"'`.

On the other hand, you can capture the target url with `'>[^<]+'` (this means: all characters after `'>'` until a `'<'` is met). So this gives you the replacement string:

```
substring(regexp_substr(link, '>[^<]+') from 2)
```

Final expression:

```
regexp_replace(
    link, 
    'href="[^"]+"',
    concat('hef="https://', substring(regexp_substr(link, '>[^<]+') from 2), '"')
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=801099f3916ecf17ed17eea18800aaaa)**

Original data:

```
select link from mytable;
```

```
| link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| <a href="https://example.com/full/?api=0aca610f4a9983fc1fa30brs6c302f970ae87c29da&amp;url=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3c0Mi56aXBwfseXNoYXJlLmNvbS92L1IwVlNwZkk4L2ZpbGUuaHRtbA==&amp;type=2" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">www.example.net/v/R0V82dSpfI8/file.html</a> |
| <a href="https://example.com/full/?api=sd4a5sdf540c1fa30b6c302f9704a6sadf&amp;url=asdfa54asd5fa5sdfa8dRcFFcafasdf==&amp;type=2" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">example.org/000hcwoc0kcwy1/545da45a.rar.html</a>                                         |
```

Query:

```
select 
    regexp_replace(
        link, 
        'href="[^"]+"',
        concat('hef="https://', substring(regexp_substr(link, '>[^<]+') from 2), '"')
    ) new_link
from mytable
```

```
| new_link                                                                                                                                                 |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| <a hef="https://www.example.net/v/R0V82dSpfI8/file.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">www.example.net/v/R0V82dSpfI8/file.html</a>           |
| <a hef="https://example.org/000hcwoc0kcwy1/545da45a.rar.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">example.org/000hcwoc0kcwy1/545da45a.rar.html</a> |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. its working but i need "like" operator. because this links are parts of html (i mean, links are in the content column of wp_posts table)

wp_post table 
PostID   ----- PostContent
1 --- <p> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="https://example.com/asdladsasadla">example.net/asdfasdfas</a> lorem ipsum dolor sit </a></p> ....